# Question(s) with the "featured" tag not showing in the side bar?

Tags: support, tags, sidebar, community-bulletin, featured-tag

On [Cryptography.SE](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) we currently have [a featured meta question](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1159/23623) but it is not showing in the side bar as can be seen on the below picture. This behavior was reproduced by one of my co-mods.

[image: Freehand Circle around missing question]

Is this a bug? Should we blame caching? If it is a bug, would removing and re-adding the tag help?

<sub>I'm asking this on the general Meta.SE because it may affect other sites as well.</sub>

Comment: Looks like it fixed itself

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Answer (score 5):

It appears the issue fixed itself...

This may be due to some internal refresh of the system or due to me removing and re-adding the tag (within the grace period). I guess we'll not find out for now...

Answer (score 3):

The "featured" sidebar only updated once every 24 hours approximately. If you've featured a question today, it will appear there tomorrow, or later the same day whenever the update task runs.

So yes, blame caching.